# How to change the "firstDay" option of the datepicker JQuery UI element in the UI of webforms?

Tags: webforms

Where can I change the firstDay option of the datepicker in the UI of webforms? Can it only be done by writing some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the date picker 'First day of week' via 'Regional settings'
(/admin/config/regional/settings)

[image: Regional settings: First day of week]